# Why assigning self.imageView to a new constant?

Tags: swift, firebase, uiimageview, firebase-storage

I came across the below Swift code snipped in Firebase documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files):

```
    // Reference to an image file in Firebase Storage
let reference = storageRef.child("images/stars.jpg")

// UIImageView in your ViewController
let imageView: UIImageView = self.imageView

// Placeholder image
let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "placeholder.jpg")

// Load the image using SDWebImage
imageView.sd_setImage(with: reference, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)
```

In this particular example, why did they need to assign self.imageView to a new constant and then use that new imageView instead? Why not using the main self.imageView?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason I can imagine is that they wanted to make it clear that an image view exists. There is absolutely no reason to reassign the image view, especially considering that they have the same exact name.